# Python ElementTree HTTP response string ParseError

Tags: python, xml, web-services, elementtree

I am parsing XML using ElementTree in Python. When I parse the XML from string it works fine, but when I parse a string from HTTP response I get:

```
ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

Code:

```
params = urllib.urlencode({'service':'A','U': 'user', 'pw': 'pw'})
f  = urllib.urlopen("http://localhost/default.aspx?%s" % params)
response = f.read()
reponse_1 = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><DATA><key id="SESSIONID">fb48b53fec5840bf9327b243d3e4f126</key></DATA>"""
root = ET.fromstring(response)
```

When I do:

```
ET.fromstring(response_1)
```

It works, but when I do the same thing from HTTP response. I get `ParseError`. I have checked that the response if of type `str` and otherwise it looks exactly the same.

What's happening here?

Comment: Put in a sanity check: `assert response == response_1`. If False, post `repr(response)`. If True, there should be no ParseError.